# what is wrong with the code for $http request?

Tags: javascript, http, angularjs

My index.html is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>HTTP Request</title>

  <script src="angularjs"></script>
  <script src="appjs"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

        Test here : <input ng-model="testString">
        <p>Test String is : {{testString}}</p>
        <button ng-click="search()">Send HTTP Request</button>
        <p>Response:</p>
        {{data}}
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And my app.js is :

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.testString = "Hello....";

        $scope.search = function() {
//          alert("inside search");
            $http.get('www.google.com', {},
                function(response) {
                    $scope.data = response;
                    alert("success");
                },
                function(failure) {
                    alert("failure");
            });
        };
    }]);
```

And it is getting inside search() function according to the alert("inside search"). But I am neither getting response nor failure. What am I supposed to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.success` and `.error` to retrieve results as per [Angular http docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) e.g.

```
$http.get('http://www.google.com').
    success(function(response) {
                $scope.data = response;
                alert("success");
            }).
    error(function(failure) {alert("failure")});
```

Comment: I just checked and this is working fine. I verified using firebug tool that I am getting a json response back. But I am unable to assign it to $scope.data as I have used {{data}} in my HTML but nothing is showing up there. Could you please help me on this? Now the problem comes down to receiving the http response and showing it back to HTML page. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $http.get('www.google.com', {},
            function(response) {
                $scope.data = response;
                alert("success");
            },
            function(failure) {
                alert("failure");
});
```

Replace To:

```
$http.jsonp('http://www.google.com', {})
         .success(function(response, status) {
             $scope.data = response;
                alert("success");
        })
        . error(function(data, status) {
             alert("failure");
     });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PJMRg/)

Comment: Thank you Nitish for your help. I understood now.
:)